# How to mirror the outer positions with the variable with R

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
 tes <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                      y = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                      d = c(10, 20, 30, 100, 11, 12, 403, 43, 21))
```

They look like this on the plot

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = tes) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(d)), size = 5)
```

[image]

I'd like to "mirror the outer rows in this data to obtain such data and plot

```
 tes1 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
                       y = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,   0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                       d = c(10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 100, 100, 11, 12, 12, 403, 403, 43, 21, 21, 403, 403, 43, 21, 21))
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = tes1) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(d)), size = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're after?

Explanation: We first convert `tes` into a flattened table with `ftable(xtabs(...)`. Then we simply replicate the first and last column, and first and last row. We then give new column and row names to reflect the extra "flanking" rows and columns, and  finally convert back to a long `dataframe` with `data.frame(table(...))`

```
# Convert to table then matrix
m <- ftable(xtabs(d ~ x + y, data = tes));
class(m) <- "matrix";

# Replicate first and last column/row by binding to the beginning
# and end, respectively of the matrix
m <- cbind(m[, 1], m, m[, ncol(m)]);
m <- rbind(m[1, ], m, m[nrow(m), ]);

# Set column/row names
rownames(m) <- seq(min(tes$x) - 1, max(tes$x) + 1);
colnames(m) <- seq(min(tes$y) - 1, max(tes$y) + 1);

# Convert back to long dataframe
tes.ext <- data.frame(as.table(m));
colnames(tes.ext) <- colnames(tes);

# Plot
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = tes.ext) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(d)), size = 5)
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
tes <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                  y = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                  d = c(10, 20, 30, 100, 11, 12, 403, 43, 21))
```